# Whats the point of the tzizit in back?

Tags: tzitzis, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

If tzizit are supposed to remind you of Hashem and the Mitzvoh whats the point of the tzizit in back? It's rare you see them at all even if you don't tuck them in.

Comment: But you do have to move them out of the way when you sit down, hold them and look at them by Kriyas Shema, etc. I'm very much aware of my tzitzis in back ;)

Comment: The only "point" is that a four cornered garment needs tzitzit on each corner. It doesn't matter if you see them.

Comment: Have you thought about the fact others can see them? And maybe more important it is as if the tzitzit which reminds us of the commandments are surrounding us. For me it's symbolic, a methaphor, for I want to surround myself with them in my everyday life. A lot of what we do on the outside reflects what we feel on the inside. And Besides that HaShem gave us a lot of commandments to make certain items which reflect a lot more as they appear to present.

Comment: P.s. see https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2969671/jewish/Why-Must-a-Tallit-Have-Four-Fringed-Corners.htm

Comment: The link I provides reasons behind the command of having tzitzit on the four corners of our garment.

Comment: I would like to quote Rav Asher Meir: "The fringes are also compared to a special badge which we wear to show OTHERS that we are servants of Hashem, and this is related to the first idea.  The garment reminds us as well as others of our unique Jewish identity and dissuades us from un-Jewish behavior.  Not only do the tzitzit remind us of our obligation to keep the commandments, but they also remind us that others, even non-Jews, have certain expectations of us which we should strive to fulfill."

Answer (score 3):

We have two tzitzit in the front and two in the back; two on the right and two on the left. We are thus surrounded by the mitzvah of tzitzit. Since the blessing is "to be wrapped in tzitzit", we try to do as we say.

*Orach Chayim 8:4.*

> One should have this intention in wrapping: That God commanded us to
>   wrap ourselves in it in order to remember all of his commandments and
>   to do them.
>
> One should have two of the fringes in front, and two behind, in order
>   to be surrounded by the commandments.

Comment: The parsha of *tzitzit* says "You should **see** it.." Does that mean that there is a requirement to see all the tzitzit on all 4 corners? I think OP may be asking about that, though that aspect is unclear.

Comment: @DanF I only answered the part: 'what's the point of the tzitzit on the back' and I also provided a link in a commentary on possible reasons or the command to make four corners on  the garment. But your right, it could be possible that the OP only wants to know if all four tzitzit need to be seen by the person who wears them, although I would say they just need to be visible (possibly for anyone) in order to notice them at which point it helps to remind us of the mitzvot..

Comment: @DanF the answer may be found in Bamidbar 15:39 HaShem commands us to look upon them, which requires an action from our side. So even if they are in the back we can take them in our hands in order to look upon them.

Comment: @DanF Most of the times a more general emphasize is put upon a command by using the term 'lecha'  but in Bamidbar 15:38-39, the “you (lachem)" that is commanded is plural. Likewise the “you” in “that you may look upon it and remember all the commandments” is not singular, it is plural. That could mean that the tzitzit are primarily not only for the wearer, but also for others who will see them.

Comment: @DanF should I put this into a answer?

Comment: Dan f That's indeed what I'm asking. I also find Levi's answer in the comments about the plural "you" interesting though Itd be great if he found a source.

Comment: @Orion Tzitzit means to “appear in visible form; [as a visual]” (Rabbi S.R.Hirsch) it refers to the tzitzit themselves or their role as a visible symbol meant to "be seen" (based on the root l'hatzitz, to see; Rashi a.o) but the tzitzit aren't only visible to ourselves but also to others.

Comment: @Orion .. This is the plain meaning of the words as shown in Bamidbar 15:39 (you could look for similar usage in other verses or look at conjuncgation tables to see their meaning) in it's literal translation could be rendered as: והיה לכם "And it shall be for/to you/y'all (plural)", לציצת which according to Hirsch has the meaning of  'as a external visibility', וראיתם "and it shall/will be seen by you (masculine plural)...

Comment: @Orion therefore I would say it could be translated as: "and it shall be a external visibility for you all, and it shall be seen by you all", which ofcourse could refer to all the individuals having their own tzitzit to look upon, our to all as a group which wear tzitzit which may be serve as a visual reminder for all who will look upon them.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a source, these are just notes I once made based on a shiur.

Comment: @Orion according to the Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim article 17 Women are not commanded to wear tzitzit. In such a case the translation I gave helps even women to remember all the commandments which are applied to them.